# docker on windows 10 with VVV

Tags: docker, vagrant

I've been using VVV on a Win 10 Pro machine for local dev.  And it works great.

But I want to try things like wpgraphql via docker.

I've read about Docker Desktop for Windows vs. Docker Toolbox. We would prefer not to use the legacy solution ( Docker Tookbox ).

Is it possible to use Docker Desktop for Windows on the same machine that is using VirtualBox ( VVV ) ?

I'm not opposed to using Docker for all our local dev sites, but it would be nice to have the option to use either.  Or at least be able to test Docker without hosing our VVV setup.

Comment: I'd say yes. Definitely possible. But I'd need to try it out myself to be 100% sure. Which I'd suggest to you: Simply try it out yourself then you'll know with certainty :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to use Docker Desktop for Windows with Vagrants due to Docker's use of Hyper-V.
Docker Toolbox can be used but it is a legacy version and getting localhost to work is a pain. 
Instead, we set up Mint on an old laptop and installed Docker CE and it works great.

Comment: I went through the same journey of interest, curiosity, frustration, and eventual disappointment.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. As the lead developer I can confirm that VVV can work with Hyper-V, just set the provider to Hyper-V. Or better yet, just install the WPGraphQL plugin on a site in VVV

Comment: Docker no longer needs Hyper-V, it now integrates with Windows Subsystem for Linux 2. Not sure about running VVV with Docker using WSL...still trying it out.

Answer (score 1):

Backup your database, destroy the VM, set the provider to Hyper-V, then reprovision and restore the database. Now your VVV instance is using Hyper-V instead of VirtualBox.

Then you should be able to run docker on Windows and still use VVV. But for something like WP GraphQL, it's overkill to setup a brand new local environment from scratch just to install a plugin to test.

*In future, ask the VVV team on GitHub and Slack though, Docker and VVV are both offtopic here*